# The method sendKeys(String) is undefined for the type ByJava(67108964) with sendKeys method while working in VS Code using Selenium through Java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, visual-studio-code, findelement

I am using Selenium writing in Java by VS Code.

I am unable to compile this line of code since there is a red line under the method `sendKeys`.

The line of code is:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath")).sendKeys("Cologne");
```

Error is shown as:

```
The method sendKeys(String) is undefined for the type ByJava(67108964)
```

Comment: Have you imported `Keys`? If yes, what is the exact error?

Comment: Yes. The exact error is: The method sendKeys(String) is undefined for the type ByJava(67108964).

Comment: When I change the line using cssSelector instead of xpath to reach the WebElement the problem get fixed automatically. why is that?

Comment: Based on the error message seems 'import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement' and/or 'import org.openqa.selenium.By' are missing. If all imports are OK check dependecies and libs.

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
The method sendKeys(String) is undefined for the type ByJava(67108964)
```

...implies that there is a configuration issue within the environmental settings.

---

As per this discussion [Solution for sendkeys(CharSequence) in Selenium](http://learn-automation.com/solution-for-sendkeyscharsequence-in-selenium/) while you start writing code using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491)'s [java](/questions/tagged/java) client, at times your project *Java Compiler* version will be below v**1.5** and `sendKeys()` will won't be read by the compiler. In these cases you need to upgrade the compiler version to 1.5 and above.

[image: JavaCompiler]

---

### Solution

You need to make the following changes:

- Change the compiler version from old version to 1.5 or greater.
- Additionally, you may need to go to `Java Build Path` -> `Libraries` -> `Select Java SE 1.8` (if Java 8 is installed)

Comment: Thanks for explaining but if that is the problem why sendKeys is recognized after using cssSlector instead of xpath? I mean, if there is a problem with configuration, sendKeys should not be recognized anyway; neither by the use of xpath nor cssSelector.